# endl doesn't work with wstring (unicode)

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, newline, wstring

Here is the code:

```
  std::ofstream f("file1.txt");
  f<<"123"<<std::endl<<"456";           //(*1)

  /*std::stringstream ordinary_strstream; This works too
  ordinary_strstream<<"123"<<'\n'<<"456";
  f<<ordinary_strstream.str();*/

  std::wstringstream s;
  s<<L"123"<<std::endl<<L"456";         //(*2)
  s<<L"123"<<L"\n"<<L"456";             //(*3) 
  s<<"123"<<WCHAR(13)<<WCHAR(10)<<"456";//(*4)

  HANDLE h =CreateFileW(L"file2.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  ULONG l;
  WriteFile(h, s.str().c_str(), s.str().length() * 2, &l, NULL);
```

In the (*1) case there is a newline, in the (*2) and (*3) i see no newline in the file2.txt. In the (*3) there is a newline. I use `notepad.exe` for browsing. Hex editor shows no `0x0D` byte, only `0x0A`.

How should i properly put the newline in unicode text file? Thank you.

Comment: That `2` should be `sizeof(wchar_t)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: ``2`` is just for abridgement, in original code there is std::wstring::value_type of course.

Comment: Careful with your terminology. Unicode is a specification of code points. Technically what you store in a file is an encoding of Unicode. If you are using Windows and wchar_t this is probably UTF-16

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's expected: `std::endl` writes a `L'\n'` to a wide-char stream (and flushes it, but it's not relevant here), never `L"\r\n"`. It's even more obvious when writing a literal `L"\n"`. `WriteFile` doesn't perform any kind of newline substitution, neither does `wstringstream` (note that file streams **do** perform newline substitution when opened in text mode, and that's why you get a proper newline in `(*1)`). Therefore, in the file there will be no carriage return characters. If you want them, write them explicitely.

Comment: You mean that it just takes the first part of "\n" (0x0A), add zero in order to form wide char, put the char in ``wstringstream`` and throws the second part (0x0D) away? Do i understand right?

Comment: @fogbit: no, nothing is thrown away. You've written the code so that it writes a `L'\n'`, so the `wstringstream` writes a `L'\n'` to its internal string. Nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't know that you really mean `L"\r\n"`, so if you want it, tell it so.

Comment: @fogbit: what do you mean by "ordinary strings"?

Comment: I mean ``std::string`` and ``std::stringstream``

Comment: @fogbit: if you mean the commented out piece you've just added, it's because you're writing to a file stream opened in text mode. It's the file stream what converts the newlines, not the string stream.

Comment: you are right, i set ``ios::binary`` mode for stream ``f`` and got no newline in the file. Now it's clear for me, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Stringstreams don't do line-ending conversion. `std::endl` is exactly the same as `\n` (char or wchar, depending on context).

`CreateFile` doesn't do line-ending conversion; it's strictly binary.

So when you create a string with a stringstream and write it to a file with `CreateFile`, an `endl` will just be a newline (`0x0A`) character.

Notepad doesn't cope well with files whose line endings are just newlines instead of CR+LF.

Comment: But ordinary stringstream does it. I've updateв the code, try if you want.

Comment: It's the `fstream` you're writing to, not the stringstream, that does the conversion.